# iframe allow-scripts doesn't return result as expected

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Why can't see the result  with sandbox="allow-scripts"
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_iframe_sandbox_origin
[image]

as it is supposed to from html source https://www.w3schools.com/tags/demo_iframe_sandbox_origin.htm

[image]

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1>The iframe sandbox attribute</h1>

  <iframe src="demo_iframe_sandbox_origin.htm" sandbox="allow-scripts">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>

  <p>Try removing the sandbox attribute value, or changing it.</p>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the MDN documentation for `sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe):

> allow-same-origin: If this token is not used, the resource is treated as being from a special origin that always fails the same-origin policy (potentially preventing access to data storage/cookies and some JavaScript APIs).

You haven't included that so the Ajax request fails.